# Cloudy blue-ish eye with redness inside eye of a puppy

Tags: dogs, health, vision

We have a new puppy and he seems to have a cloudy/blue-ish eye (in one only).  It's not bothering him in anyway as far as we can tell; he plays/eats/etc. all as expected.

We had one vet have a look and they mentioned it was likely just a scratch to the cornea. Another vet during his last shots mentioned that we should be seeing a specialist that costs about 250 dollars just for the first visit.

What could this be, how worried should we be, and what options do we have?

Comment: WE aren't generally veterinary professionals, and you have already seen two different vets. I would suggest asking the second one for more detail about why the specialist would be necessary, but beyond that I am not sure we can help you any more than they already have.

Comment: I would recommend going to a vet that specializes in optometrist. The 250 may save you money down the road if there is something major going on and if it isn't you will have the definate answer and peace of mind.

Comment: I agree with the others, a vet is needed. You could also try to take a clear picture and post it here. If anyone can give you an indication of what I could be, that will help.

Comment: NOTE that some vets will provide a discount if you are not able to pay their full fee and discuss it with them first.  It does not cost anything to contact the specialist.  They may even offer a suggest for your local vet to consider.

Comment: You've seen two vets and they gave you conflicting advice, neither of which sounds "right" to me. Why two vets?

Answer (score 3):

My late dog had a similar situation with her eyes (but in both) for years. The vet told us that it was fatty buildup that shouldn't affect her vision but that she should go on diet food anyway. The diet food didn't seem to help. We never determined what the actual cause was, but she didn't seem to have issues with her vision.

But as the folks in the comments have said, really the best thing for you to do is to see a vet, a specialist if necessary. The best we can do for you here is to speculate.